# prevent javascript from breaking when xml has an empty node value

Tags: javascript, xml

I have example the following xml:

```
<LOCAL_AUTHORITY>
     <NAME>Derby</NAME>
     <REGION></REGION>
     <IRD>22%</IRD>
<LOCAL_AUTHORITY>
```

I have the following javascript:

```
localAuthorities=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LOCAL_AUTHORITY");
alert(localAuthorities[0].getElementsByTagName("REGION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
alert('This get triggered so javascript is not broken');
```

My question is that the javascript breaks unless you give region a value in the xml. Kind reagrds to any responders.. how do i prevent it from breaking?

Comment: not sure if I understand it correctly but as I see it, the element `REGION` has no child nodes... so `.getElementsByTagName("REGION")[0].childNodes[0]` is likely what's failing.. try to check whether all parts of this path are not null or undefined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure there is something there before you read it. basic idea:

```
var nodes = localAuthorities[0].getElementsByTagName("REGION")[0].childNodes;
var value = nodes.length===1 ? nodes[0].nodeValue : "";
alert(value);
```

Comment: @TheHulk The value is empty, not the tag is missing.

Answer (score -1):

You can do :

```
localAuthorities=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LOCAL_AUTHORITY");
// validate if there is region or not
if (localAuthorities[0].getElementsByTagName("REGION")[0].val()){
  alert(localAuthorities[0].getElementsByTagName("REGION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  alert('This get triggered so javascript is not broken');
}
```

Comment: Does not answer user's problem. You are looking to see if the element `region` is there. That is not the issue.

Comment: It does , the user want to prevent it from breaking